# Regex to exctact url substring

Tags: regex

Is there a way to write a regex,in one line,able to catch only specific part of url like this? :

```
ftp://trial.com:50/papers/history.pdf
```

getting  only ftp, trial.com and 50.

```
market://find/tools/new
```

getting only market and find

Comment: How do you have a regexp with no language and no tools?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
\/\/|\/.*|(\w+)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/kF4kI3/3)

Explaining:

```
            # match without grouping what you do not want
\/\/        # two slashes
|           # OR
\/.*        # everything after the first alone-slash
|           # OR
            # now match grouping what you want
(\w+)       # each desired word in group 1
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it works, but it catches also `://`. There is a way to avoid it?

Comment: *getting only ftp, trial.com and 50.* - I guess OP means as different groups.

Comment: @user1938193. What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes it seems like he used "regex101.com" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is how to extract a part of the matching string, not how to match the whole string.  Some tools allow use of parentheses marks (which must be escaped) for this purpose.  Consider this example with `sed`:

```
 echo ftp://trial.com/hist.pdf | sed 's/^\(.\+\):\/\/\([^\/]\+\)\/\?.*$/\1 \2/'
```

The `sed` command is s/*regexp*/*replacement*/ so it matches the *regexp* and replaces it with *replacement*.  This tags the `.\+` part within the parentheses which is printed in the output with `\1`.  The part between the second parentheses is what comes after the // and before the next /.  This is printed with `\2` in the replacement.  Using `\+` means a non-zero sequence (at least one) instead of `*` which is zero or more.  The parentheses must be escaped to tag the substrings for use in the replacement, otherwise they just mean parentheses characters.

The `^` signifies the beginning of the line.  `.\+` is at least one character of something.  The `:\/\/` matches the ://.  The `[^\/]\+` between the second parentheses is at least one character that is not / followed by `\/\?` (an optional /).  Lastly, the `.*$` is everything until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w+):\/\/([\w\.]+)(:(\d+))?.*
```

Or a less restrictive version (be careful):

```
(.+?):\/\/([^:\/\?]+)(:(\d+))?.*
```

And the groups:

`$1` is the protocol
`$2` is the domain
`$4` is the port (optional)

Examples and explanations [here](https://regex101.com/r/cF5pG1/3).

Comment: Could you fix the example url? It doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: You do not need to escape the dot inside brackets